# Route command output

Tags: networking, routing

Route command output:

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.10    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
$
```

From the above output the following are the doubts I have:

1. What is 0.0.0.0 means in destination and gateway column
2. If the packet is sent from 192.168.2.36 ip, what is the gateway for that. It use 192.168.2.10 or 0.0.0.0
3. Lets consider I have one more network with ip 192.168.1.0. If the packet is sent from any of the host from this network, what is the
   gateway for that ip.
4. What is default gateway.

Answer (score 1):

> What is 0.0.0.0 means in destination and gateway column

The "destination" column, together with the "genmask", is a *mask* that the destination address must match: `(packet_destination & route_mask) == route_destination`. So a route with destination `0.0.0.0` & mask `0.0.0.0` matches everything – it is the default route.

In the "gateway" column, `0.0.0.0` is merely a placeholder showing that there's no gateway at all, and all matching hosts are reachable directly. So the second route is a *local* one.

The routing table can become slightly clearer when written in the `ip route` format:

```
$ ip -n route show
0.0.0.0/0 via 192.168.2.10 dev eth0
192.168.2.0/24 dev eth0
```

> If the packet is sent from 192.168.2.36 ip, what is the gateway for that. It use 192.168.2.10 or 0.0.0.0

Your routing table doesn't describe the source, **only destination,** so the question cannot be answered based purely on that.

If the packet were sent *to* `192.168.2.36`, then it would match the `192.168.2.0/24` route and wouldn't use any gateway.

And if you actually meant *incoming* packets, then your routing table doesn't apply to those at all – only the *sender's* routing table determines the gateway, not the receiver's.

> Lets consider I have one more network with ip 192.168.1.0. If the packet is sent from any of the host from this network, what is the gateway for that ip.

If you're *receiving* the packets, then your routing table is irrelevant. So the question can be answered only based on the *sender's* routing table.

If you're *sending packets to* `192.168.1.x`, they only match the `0.0.0.0/0` route, so they would use `192.168.2.10` as the gateway.

> What is default gateway.

The "default gateway" is the gateway that the *default route* has.

The "default route" is `0.0.0.0/0` (destination `0.0.0.0` mask `0.0.0.0`).

So your "default gateway" is `192.168.2.10`.